# Data not being sent into buffer correctly?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to make a system where i pass data from buffers to vertex shaders using attributes, i already have some, but this new system isnt working. I am trying to pass a singular integer to my vertex shader. I know for a fact all my other systems work and the data going into the buffer is correct. The matrices work correctly when i place an int instead of the attribute, so i know it's something to do with the buffers.

I have tested ALL my systems. It is literally down to the fact when i insert the integer attribute into the operator of my array in the vertex shader, it will NOT work even if it's not directly in it and i set another int to the integer. and i end up with a fully white screen, for some reason when i make the attribute 3 instead of 4 the screen becomes red. if i make it 1, it still becomes white. The value of the data going into the glbufferdata is 1 and i made sure it is the correct length and has a pair for EACH vertex.

```
        if (reload == 1)
        {
            char scenepath[32] = "Gamedata\\Scenes\\Scene01.map";

            LoadScene(scenepath);

            for (size_t i = 0; i < ObjNames.size(); i++)
            {
                loadobj(modelloc[i]);
            }

            reorder_index();

            //glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);
            //glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index.size() * sizeof(int), &index[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);




            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);


            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normals.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, objbuffer);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, model_index.size() * sizeof(int), &model_index[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW); 



            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

            glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
            glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

            glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, objbuffer);  //not workinngggg
            glVertexAttribPointer(3, 1, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);


        }
```

}

```
#version 430
layout(location = 0) in vec3 v_pos;
//layout (location = 1) in vec3 uv;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 v_Normal;
layout (location = 3) in int object;
out vec3 FragPos;  
out vec3 Normalout;
uniform mat4 outmatrix[];
uniform mat4 model;
void main() {

gl_Position = outmatrix[object] * vec4(v_pos, 10.0f);
FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(v_pos , 0.0));

Normalout =  v_Normal;

}
```

I am expecting the integer from attribute 3 to go into outmatrix[interger_here], to produce the desired results of having multiple matrices in my game.

i look forward to your support as i'm really clueless and the screen being different colors depending on attrib location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define an array of generic integral vertex attribute data, then you have t o use [`glVertexAttribIPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) (focus on the **`I`**) rather than `glVertexAttribPointer`:

```cpp
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, objbuffer); 
glVertexAttribIPointer(3, 1, GL_INT, 0, (void*)0);
```

Note, `glVertexAttribPointer` in the combination with an integral datatype (e.g. `GL_INT`) converts the integral attributes to floating point values.

---

It is not valid that an array of uniform variables is indexed by an attribute!

See [OpenGL Shading Language 4.30 Specification - 4.3.9 Interface Blocks; page 53](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.30.pdf)

> **A uniform** or shader storage **block array can only be indexed with a dynamically uniform integral expression**, otherwise results are undefined.

(in the most recent GLSL version 4.60, this stays the same)

Note, uniform variables are stored in the default uniform block and an attribute is not "dynamically uniform" because it may be different for each run of the vertex shader.

This means, accoriding to the specification, the result of your code is undefined.

> ```
> #version 430
>
> // [...]
> layout (location = 3) in int object;
> uniform mat4 outmatrix[];
>
> void main()
> {
>     // [...]
>     gl_Position = outmatrix[object] * vec4(v_pos, 10.0f);
> }
> ```

---

An workaround would be to encode the matrices to an 2 dimensional (4 * N) texture with the internal format [`GL_RGBA32F`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml):

```cpp
const int N = ...;
std::vector<glm::mat4> outmatrix(N);

GLuint tbo;
glGenTextures(1, tbo);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tbo);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, 4, N, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, outmatrix.data());
```

Get the matrix values out of the texture by using [`texelFetch`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texelFetch.xhtml):

```c
#version 430

 layout(location = 3) in int object;

 layout(binding=0) uniform sampler2D outmatrix;

 // [...]

 void main()
 {
    mat4 outMat = mat4(
        texelFetch(outmatrix, ivec2(0, object), 0),
        texelFetch(outmatrix, ivec2(1, object), 0),
        texelFetch(outmatrix, ivec2(2, object), 0),
        texelFetch(outmatrix, ivec2(3, object), 0)
    );

    // [...]

}
```

Comment: Seems like it should had work, since i noticed that adding a float instead of a int directly in the shader produces the same blank screen, however i still get the same result :/ i double checked and i'm 100% sure that integrals are entering. It seems like i have the buffer binding and stuff mis matched and the wrong data is entering attrib 4 but i really dont know how to fix that.

Comment: i replaced it with `glVertexAttribIPointer(3, 1, GL_INT, 0, (void*)0);` but it doesnt solve the problem :/ But was probably part of it.

Comment: Yes, i know that. That's why i made sure of it, every vert has it's own integral. I think the shader just crashes.

Comment: Yes, there are 2 outmatrixs. I tested them both by directly adding 0, or 1. (the same data in the model_index) .

Comment: @Augustsinyukov What you try to do is not valid. See the answer. This seems to be som kind of [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you try to achieve?

Comment: what i want is to have a single integer attribute, where i can use it as an operator for a array of matrices.

Comment: but i already have sending the matrices done, the problems i'm having is using the attribute as an operator crashes the shader.

Comment: @Augustsinyukov Yes I know, but you won't get rid of that, because the specification doesn't allow it.

Comment: wait so i cant use a attribute as a operator?

Comment: @Augustsinyukov An attribute cant be the array index of an uniform variable, that all what the specification says.

Comment: Well that sucks, i guess i am forced to have a matrix per vert or something else :/

Comment: @Augustsinyukov `GL_RGBA32F` texture. See the answer.

Comment: is it an efficient method?

Comment: @Augustsinyukov I've used this approach for the bone matrices of morphing technology